# Django ORM: why there are this additional queries?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have this kind of models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pass

class Price(models.Model):
    [...]
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='prices')

class Spec(models.Model):
    [...]
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='specs')
```

And view:

```
class ProductsList(ListView):
    [...]
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        [...]
        products_ids_list = [some list of products ids from search]
        prices = models.Price.objects.filter(product__id__in=products_ids_list).order_by('-id')

        prices = { '%s!%s' % (item.product.__class__.__name__, item.product_id): item for item in prices }
```

I hope i didn't broken anything when simplifying my code ;)

For some reasons, I can't use here select_related/prefetch_related (doesn't matter now, i want to know what's happen there).

Now, i have cached prices, everything works fine, but django-toolbar shows me that in line where I create a dictionary with prices, i have a query for **every price** (it fetches **product**):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 10

Connection: default

/products/views.py in get(106)
  response = super(ProductsList, self).get(request, *a, **b)
/products/views.py in get_context_data(79)
  prices = { '%s!%s' % (item.product.__class__.__name__, item.product_id): item for item in prices }
/products/views.py in <dictcomp>(79)
  prices = { '%s!%s' % (item.product.__class__.__name__, item.product_id): item for item in prices }
```

Why it's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've asked it to fetch the product, by requesting `item.product`.

Not sure why you're doing that though, since `item.product.__class__` will always be the same.

Comment: +1 because the second line is exactly what I was going to ask.

Comment: Oh, item.product.__class__.__name__ - I'm blind :/ You are right.
And my example is very simplified, i have more then one price type in there. OK, now i have some way to go, thanks :)

Comment: [Content types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) (and generic relations) might be useful for you if you have different types.

Comment: @DanielRoseman OK, i will try - currently I have my own hacks for this, and they are not so simple ;) Thanks!